# University's wired connection doesn't work

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, vpn, ethernet

My university has a very poor Wi-Fi coverage, hence my need to connect my laptop to an Ethernet port instead.
The problem is that wired conenction can only be used by computers of the university.
So I tested it by myself and I didn't achieve to connect to the Internet through the ethernet.

Does a VPN can solve this problem (I already have a vpn server that I can connect to), or any other solutions ?

Thanks by advance !

Comment: You need to talk to the university IT help desk.

Answer (score 2):

More than likely the networking switch will be either a managed network switch which will only allow specific MAC addresses ([MAC Filtering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_filtering)) or it will use something like [802.1X](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.1X) for authentication.

If they have specifically told you not to use those connections (probably as they will be on a different network and may have different levels of trust/firewall rules than their student WiFi network) or believe they have implemented measures to stop you because they don't want you to be using them, then attempting to use them could cause legal problems for you and so I would not attempt any further.